OpenJPA Factory and Externalizer, StoreContext give access to EntityManager instance?
Is there a way to get access to an active EntityManager instance using StoreContext ctx variable? Variable is visible in a factory+externalizer functions
// use custom methods to dbDateTimeAsStr-to-calendar and calendar-to-dbDateTimeAsStr
@Column(name="updated_utc") @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
@Factory("JPAUtils.db2cal") @Externalizer("JPAUtils.cal2db")
private Calendar updated;

- - - 

public static String cal2db(Calendar val, StoreContext ctx) {
    // convert calendar to db datetime string to be used in InsertUpdate sql queries
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return df.format(val.getTime());

    //TODO: EntityManager em = ctx.getEntityManager() how to do this?
}

public static Calendar db2cal(String val, StoreContext ctx) {
    // convert from UTC string to utc calendar object
    int y = Integer.parseInt(val.substring(0, 4));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(val.substring(5, 7));
    int d = Integer.parseInt(val.substring(8, 10));
    int h = Integer.parseInt(val.substring(11, 13));
    int mi= Integer.parseInt(val.substring(14, 16));
    int s = Integer.parseInt(val.substring(17, 19));
    int millis = (val.length() > 20 ? Integer.parseInt(val.substring(20)) : 0 );
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC") );
    cal.set(y, m-1, d, h, mi, s);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millis);
    return cal;
}

